# Dev-C++ Hello world doesn't show

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I downloaded and run Dev-C++ and I write and run F9 this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello, world!";
   return 0;
}
```

But no "Hello, world!" is printed, why?

Comment: Probably because your IDE is hiding the output from you somehow.

Comment: a black screen appears and disappears in a sec...

Comment: The program is doing exactly as you stated.  It will run, and close down.  Run the program from the command-line.

Comment: Set a debug breakpoint on `return 0;`. Breakpoints are your friend.

Comment: I have return 0.....

Comment: Offtopic, google Orwell Dev C++, It is a pretty decent compiler and IDE. Original DevC++ and wxDevC++ are not up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello, world!";
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Add `getchar()` at the end of your program as a simple "pause-method" as consoles seems to close so fast, so you need to "delay" to see your console.

Comment: `getchar()` is not declared in `<iostream>`.

Answer (score 4):

Many IDE users have this problem.  The program runs but it closes before you can see its results on the screen.  One portable fix is to add this at the bottom of `main` before you return:

```
std::cin.get();
```

That way it will wait for you to enter some text before it exits.

Comment: `cin.get()` would be simpler. No need to declare a dummy variable,

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: thank you, I made that change in my answer.  You're right, it's simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The output is printed to a terminal, and you don't have a newline etc.... very unlikely that you will see it, so

- Add a newline to the output
- make sure you have time to read the output before the terminal window closes (add a sleep or something)
- *Don't* use `using namespace` as that is a bad practice and *will* lead to trouble in your programming.

So like;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
   sleep(2);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am taking lessons from my university and they all use using namespace in their examples D:

Comment: You can tell them that it is a bad practice which should be discouraged -- write the full name like `std::cout` -- namespaces are there for a reason.

Comment: but why? they are never gonna let me pass the lesson if I tell 'em lol

Comment: Because you eventually will include multiple packages from namespace `xxx` and namespace `yyy` -- and both those namespaces will have a function `open` -- so now you have no clue as to whether you are calling `xxx::open` or `yyy::open` and you will end up in debug hell.

Comment: See this for why `using namespace` is bad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: You're assuming the OP is using a system that provides `<unistd.h>`.